# Java FX How to 'Stop' Thread Midway and Restart it or destroy it

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

Can't stop Thread **Midway** and **Restart** add Node Thread.

**This is what i getting**

[image]

**This is what i need** I want something like this over and over whenever i press ***Refresh Button***

**clean screen** and **Restart** (for example. A to N In proper order )

[image]

**Why?** So i can choice different List before refresh.

**Back Story** *(ignore)*
I'm working on a little project on JavaFX from a month now but this problem is bugging me. I did my research and try to figure it out but nothing. I really appreciated if someone guild me on the right path. Please highlight this question so others don't have to waste so much time

I have JavaFX Controller

```
@FXML public FlowPane flow_panel;

MyPlatform mp = new MyPlatform(); // A class that implements Runnable
Thread t;

boolean first_time_click = true; // To check Whether i clicked '1st' time or 'second' time
@FXML
private void Refresh_Btn(ActionEvent event) 
{       
    System.out.println("Refresh btn");

     t = new Thread(mp); //Creating Thread object

    if(first_time_click == true) { first_time_click = false;



        MyPlatform.stop = false; //Thread object.Stop, When false do nothing

        flow_panel.getChildren().clear(); // cleaning screen
        System.out.println("Start Thread");
        t.setDaemon(true);  
        t.start(); //Start Thread


    } else if(first_time_click == false){   first_time_click = true;



        MyPlatform.stop = true; //Exist loop
        t.interrupt(); // I thought   't.interrupt()'   it work but nothing
        System.out.println("Stop Thread");

        flow_panel.getChildren().clear(); // cleaning screen
        MyPlatform.stop = false; //Thread object.Stop, When false do nothing
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start(); //Start Thread
        System.out.println("Stoped  Thread Started again");


    } 

}
```

---

Then i have a class named MyPlatform that implements Runnable

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import setups.WindowSetupConfig;

public class MyPlatform implements Runnable
{   

public static boolean stop = false;

@Override
public void run()
{



    for (String name : ListOfNames.getlist()) 
    {
        if(stop)    // Exit for loop if true
        {
            break;
        }
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {   

                Button btn = new Button("Button : "+name);

                System.out.println(name);


        //Adding that button to FlowPane
        WindowSetupConfig.getController().flow_panel.getChildren().add(btn);
                }
            });

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // Wait for 1 sec, Controlling speed
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { // try catch it needed for some reason
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }

}
```

---

I hava a list of string. Orignally that list would have over 500 names

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListOfNames
{   
    private static ArrayList<String> list_of_names ;

    public ListOfNames()
    {
        list_of_names = new ArrayList<>();
        list_of_names.add("A");
        list_of_names.add("B");
        list_of_names.add("C");
        list_of_names.add("D");
        list_of_names.add("E");
        list_of_names.add("F");
        list_of_names.add("G");
        list_of_names.add("H");
        list_of_names.add("I");
        list_of_names.add("J");
        list_of_names.add("K");
        list_of_names.add("L");
        list_of_names.add("M");
        list_of_names.add("N");
    }


    public static ArrayList<String> getlist() {
        return list_of_names;
    }
}
```

Whenever i *press* **Refresh button** i want to stop thread **midway** of adding nods to flow panel.
[image]

Clean the FlowPane using *flow_panel.getChildren().clear();*
And restart over from start of the list

[image]

**Bacially**
**-Stop**
**-Clean**
**-Restart**

If there any way to do it with **Service** or **task** that would be great

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. And unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: basically, you cancel the task, do the cleanup stuff and then start a new task - or what am I missing?

Comment: @kleopatra yes cancel the task, cleanup and restart it, exactly. That's the problem I'm unable to cancel or stop Thread

Comment: You cannot rely on changed values of `MyPlatform.stop` to be visible to threads other than the one doing the assignment since it's not  `volatile` and therefore a copy may be created for each thread. Furthermore it's `static` so if you run multiple `MyPlatform`s all are "canceled" (assuming they get the message).

Comment: @fabian i see. Any other way to do this?

Comment: not _re-start_, create and start a new one .. @fabian all those static accessors must go anyway ;)

Comment: @kleopatra I didn't get what u mean. When I start Thread again. It makes a copy of it self. i want A,B,D,E,F,G,H,I but i get A,B,C,D,A',E,B',F,C',G,H,D',J
where A' ,B',  C', D' from other thread

Comment: probably misunderstood what you are after - provide the [mcve] to explain your problem, words or snippets are not enough, as we see here again :)

Comment: Thank you  @kleopatra I found a solution coz of you. I uploaded an answer. but I'm getting and waring on t.suspend(); Guide me to any other better way to have the same result if there is any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Solution to my problem. Now my question is there any better way to achieve the same result
Because I'm getting and yellow warring which means I'm doing it the wrong way

[image]

**Luncher.java**

```
    package project;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Luncher extends Application
{


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {


            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Window.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);          

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Luncher Failed !" +e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        launch(args);

    }

}
```

**Controller.java**

```
package project;


import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;


public class Controller implements Initializable
{


    @FXML
    public FlowPane flowPane;


    //A class that implements  Runable, So i can start a thead there
    private MyRunableClass my_run_class; 
    private Thread t; //Thread object

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {       
        new ListOfNames(); //Init list of names and creating Array list, In real program i will get this list from database
        my_run_class = new MyRunableClass(this);

    }





    @FXML
    void clear_Button(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        flowPane.getChildren().clear(); 
    }


    @FXML
    void start_Button(ActionEvent event) 
    {   
        t = new Thread(my_run_class);
        t.start();
    }

    @FXML
    void stop_Button(ActionEvent event) {
        t.suspend(); ///NOT WORKING???????? any way to stop running thread
    }




    private boolean firstTime_thread_running = true; // To check Whether i clicked '1st' time or 'second' time

    @FXML
    void refresh_Button(ActionEvent event) 
    {


        if(firstTime_thread_running == false){


            //Stop
            //  my_run_class.stop = true; //Exist loop
            t.suspend();
            System.out.println("Suspend");

        } else
        {   
            firstTime_thread_running = false;
        }



//Clean
            flowPane.getChildren().clear(); // cleaning screen
            System.out.println("Screen clear");


//Restart , well.. at least that what i want
            t = new Thread(my_run_class);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            t.start(); //Start Thread
            System.out.println("Stoped  Thread Started again"); 

    }



}
```

---

**MyRunableClass.java**

```
    package project;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class MyRunableClass implements Runnable
{       
    private Controller controller;

    public MyRunableClass(Controller controller)
    {   
        //Getting FXML Controller
        this.controller = controller;
    }

//  public boolean stop = false;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {



        for (String name : ListOfNames.getlist()) 
        {
//          if(stop)    // Exit for loop if true
//          {
//              break;
//          }
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable()
            {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {   

                    Button btn = new Button("Button : "+name);

                    System.out.println(name);

                    controller.flowPane.getChildren().add(btn);
                }
            });

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1); // Wait for half sec this time
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { // try catch it needed for some reason
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }

}
```

---

**ListOfNames.java**

```
    package project;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListOfNames
{   
    private static ArrayList<String> list_of_names ;

    public ListOfNames()
    {
        list_of_names = new ArrayList<>();
        list_of_names.add("A");
        list_of_names.add("B");
        list_of_names.add("C");
        list_of_names.add("D");
        list_of_names.add("E");
        list_of_names.add("F");
        list_of_names.add("G");
        list_of_names.add("H");
        list_of_names.add("I");
        list_of_names.add("J");
        list_of_names.add("K");
        list_of_names.add("L");
        list_of_names.add("M");
        list_of_names.add("N");
        list_of_names.add("O");
        list_of_names.add("P");
        list_of_names.add("Q");
        list_of_names.add("R");
        list_of_names.add("S");
        list_of_names.add("T");
        list_of_names.add("U");
        list_of_names.add("V");
        list_of_names.add("W");
        list_of_names.add("X");
        list_of_names.add("Y");
        list_of_names.add("Z");

    }


    public static ArrayList<String> getlist() {
        return list_of_names;
    }
}
```

---

**Window.fxml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="413.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="project.Controller">
   <children>
      <FlowPane fx:id="flowPane" layoutX="2.0" layoutY="61.0" prefHeight="352.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-border-color: #000000; -fx-border-insets: 1.1; -fx-border-width: 5;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="61.0" />
      <Button layoutX="405.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#stop_Button" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Stop" />
      <Button layoutX="313.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#start_Button" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Star" />
      <Button layoutX="497.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clear_Button" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="80.0" text="Clean" />
      <Button layoutX="40.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#refresh_Button" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="109.0" text="Refresh" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't read all of your code, but I'll give a general description on how to cancel and "restart" a `Task`.

First of all, **do not** use the `suspend`, `stop`, or `resume` methods of `Thread`; they are deprecated for a reason.

Like all background tasks, cancelling requires cooperation from the developer of said background task. The task must check at appropriate times whether or not it has been cancelled and react accordingly. Generally, this is done by querying the interruption status of the current `Thread`, but the `Task` class inherits the easier to use `isCancelled` method from `FutureTask`.

An example with simulated long-running work:

```
public class MyTask extends Task<Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10_000; i++) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                break;
            }
            updateMessage(Integer.toString(i));
            Thread.sleep(1L);
            updateProgress(i, 10_000);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

You cancel a `Task` by using the `cancel` method of the `Worker` interface. Notice the check of `isCancelled` every iteration of the loop; when the `cancel` method is invoked the `Task` will stop at the earliest opportunity. Also, calling `Worker.cancel()` (or `Future.cancel(true)`) will interrupt the `Thread` meaning any interruptible operation (e.g. `Thread.sleep`) will throw an `InterruptedException`.

You can react to when a `Task` succeeds, fails, or is cancelled by observing the properties of the `Task` or adding event handlers.

```
MyTask task = new MyTask();
task.setOnSucceeded(event -> handleSucceededTask());
task.setOnFailed(event -> handleFailedTask());
task.setOnCancelled(event -> handleCancelledTask());
```

It is these callbacks where you can do the clean up and execute a *new* `Task` as necessary. Note, you have to launch a new `Task` because a `Task` is single use.

Comment: **Thank you so much** I really appreciate your help :)